# Dplyr dataframe is not selecting top 10 or sorting values

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a function that is meant to return the top 10 customers in a DF, however, the output of my function has the unaltered DF (asides from groupings) with results out of order and also displaying every single row, despite the fact that I asked for top 10.

```
myData <- data.frame("Platform" =
 c("Digital", "Digital", "Digital", "Digital", "Digital", "Digital", "Offline", "Offline", "Offline", "Offline", "Offline"), "Cust.ID" = c("John", "Josh", "Juan", "Jason", "Jay", "Jorge", "Jurgen", "Julian", "Jules", "James", "Jimmy"),
"Input.Records" = c(100, 150, 102, 10, 111, 132, 125, 154, 101, 103, 100)) 

getTopTenCustomers <- function(platformFilter = "Digital"){
  filteredDf <- myData %>% group_by(Cust.ID, Platform) %>%
    filter(Platform == platformFilter) %>% summarise(Input.Records = sum(Input.Records)) %>%
    top_n(10) %>% arrange(myData, desc(Input.Records))
  data.frame(filteredDf)
  return(filteredDf)
}
```

Also, I'm a bit concerned about that `arrange(myData, desc(Input.Records))` call. Isn't that just arranging the rows in the original DF? Every other example I saw had the arrange at first, but that also seems concerning because, the way it seems, sorting the values before grouping and filtering might result in the filter displaying inaccurate results, wouldn't it?

Comment: A reproducible example along with expected output would help but this `arrange(myData, desc(Input.Records))` doesn't seem correct to be used in pipe.

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: I've added code to create a mock df.

As for expected output, I really just want it to be sorted and display only the top 10 entries.

Comment: Try removing `myData` from `arrange` i.e make it `arrange(desc(Input.Records))`.

Comment: I am getting an arrangement now, but it's still showing all of my rows rather than just the top 10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- When you are taking `top_n` your data is still grouped by `Cust.ID`, so we may need to `ungroup` the data before taking `top_n`.
- No need to pass dataframe in `arrange` when using pipes.
- It is better to pass dataframe explicitly in the function.

Try using this function :

```
library(dplyr)

getTopTenCustomers <- function(myData, platformFilter = "Digital"){
  filteredDf <- myData %>% 
                 group_by(Cust.ID, Platform) %>%
                 filter(Platform == platformFilter) %>% 
                 summarise(Input.Records = sum(Input.Records)) %>%
                 ungroup %>%
                 top_n(10) %>% 
                 arrange(desc(Input.Records))
  return(filteredDf)
}

getTopTenCustomers(myData)
```